# Keras: share weights between layers with different names

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The standard recipe of Keras:

```
# This layer can take as input a matrix
# and will return a vector of size 64
shared_lstm = LSTM(64)

# When we reuse the same layer instance
# multiple times, the weights of the layer
# are also being reused
# (it is effectively *the same* layer)
encoded_a = shared_lstm(tweet_a)
encoded_b = shared_lstm(tweet_b)
```

offers us to create a layer, that is shared, i.e. takes different tensors as input and output, but operates equally on them. The layer name will be something like 'lstm_1'.

Is there a way to create two distinct (convolutional) layers with different names, but sharing their kernel and bias weights?

**Update**

Let me clarify the purpose. I have an object detection model (Single shot detector) with a pyramid of feature maps. Those feature maps sit on top of each other like:

```
det_ctx1 (32x32, Conv+ReLU+MaxPool) -> det_ctx2 (16x16, Conv+ReLU+MaxPool) -> ...
```

Detection predictions are technically implemented as convolution layers producing offsets and class confidences from those feature maps:

```
det_ctx1 -> det_ctx1_conf
         -> det_ctx1_loc

   |
   \/
det_ctx2 -> det_ctx2_conf
         -> det_ctx2_loc

   |
   \/
det_ctx3 -> det_ctx3_conf
         -> det_ctx3_loc
```

`det_ctx1_conf` and `det_ctx2_conf` are semantically the same and I would like to leverage the weight sharing to get those layers trained better (under normal circumstances, training samples are assigned to certain pyramid level, so some levels have too little training samples).

Comment: It doesn't sound possible to me. It would be interesting to understand why you need this feature; maybe there is a better way to get what you want.

Comment: Not sure this exists out of the box... I imagine you could have a custom layer without owned weights that uses another layer... Maybe `Lambda(lambda x: prev_layer(x), name='RepeatLayer')(x)` works? Or maybe it messes up model compilation. Could you give more background as to why you want this?

Comment: How would these two convolutional layers be different?

Comment: Please see the updated answer for the explanation why I need this.